# Identify a photo filter or a post-processing technique

Tags: post-processing, photo-editing, effect, color-filters

Sometimes I come across photos that have some effect/filter applied to them, and I cannot understand/explain what that is. It looks really attractive, and I would like to be able to reproduce this effect in Photoshop or alike. The effect that I am looking for can be seen, for example, [here](http://openvisconf.com/). Scroll down to the photos below “About” and “Schedule.”

I would be grateful if somebody could tell the name of this effect/filter and maybe share some recipe or just a link where I could read about it.

Thank you!

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: When asking about a visual effect in a photograph, in addition to posting a sample image or a link to one, it is very, very helpful if you describe your impression of the effect briefly in the title and in more detail in the question. See [PSA on "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions) for more help and explanation. Thanks.

Comment: @mattdm, I really had no idea how to start, how to pose my question. And I didn’t know how to search for similar questions either, and it ended up being a duplicate multiple times. Thank you for the tip; I’ll certainly use it next time.

Answer (score 2):

Those images you pointed to are very low-contrast images. Several thing you should try to do is to change contrast in high low and mid tones. Also you can try to change the colors of image the saturation in HSV channel. Highly recommended, alien exposure software in which you can play with image contrasts colors ect.